# Calculate percent of each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, percentage

I've the following code to calculate the percentage of each element (like poll voting system):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#percentage").click(function() {
        var number, sumNumbers = 0, newPercent;
    
        $(".item").each(function() {
            number = $(this).children(".itemNum").text();
            number = +number;

            sumNumbers += number;

            if(sumNumbers != 0) {
              newPercent = (number / sumNumbers) * 100;
            } else {
              newPercent = 0;
            }

            $(this).children(".percentage").text(newPercent+"%");
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">
  <span class="itemNum">0</span> <span class="percentage"></span>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <span class="itemNum">2</span> <span class="percentage"></span>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <span class="itemNum">1</span> <span class="percentage"></span>
</div>

<button id="percentage">Calculate Percentage!</button>
```

But, the result is:

```
0 0%
2 100%
1 33.33333333333333%
```

So, how to calculate return the following result?

```
0 0%
2 66.66666666666667%
1 33.33333333333333%
```

I need these results to do a progress bar on my poll system, so, how to do this?

Comment: You have to get the sum first before you can calculate the percentages.

Comment: So, I've to do other `$(".item").each...` before the first `.each`? I did this and it works, but I don't know if is correct to use something like: `$(".item").each(function() {doSomething()}); $(".item").each(function() {doSomethingAgain()});` @Musa

Comment: @Igor I edited my answer to answer on *.each()* comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the text to integer via *parseInt()* function.

And you need first to sum numbers and then you can calculate percentage.

For one loop question:
You can't count percentage in one loop. Explained [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/35842/can-only-one-loop-be-used-to-calculate-percentage)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#percentage").click(function() {
        var number, sumNumbers = 0, newPercent;
         $(".item").each(function(){
               number = $(this).children(".itemNum").text();
               sumNumbers += parseInt(number);
               
          });
        $(".item").each(function() {
            number = parseInt($(this).children(".itemNum").text());

            if(sumNumbers != 0) {
              newPercent = (number / sumNumbers) * 100;
            } else {
              newPercent = 0;
            }

            $(this).children(".percentage").text(newPercent+"%");
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">
  <span class="itemNum">0</span> <span class="percentage"></span>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <span class="itemNum">2</span> <span class="percentage"></span>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <span class="itemNum">1</span> <span class="percentage"></span>
</div>

<button id="percentage">Calculate Percentage!</button>
```

Comment: Why down vote ? My snippet is working correctly as your question wanted.

Comment: I've did this, so my question was about use `.each` again... But your answer is correctly and works too. Thanks.

Comment: @Igor You're question was about not working percentage counting not about *.each* ;). No problem.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but the comment made by @Musa help me, so I just left the question about `.each`...